# How to stop proguard from obfuscating entire package?

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

I need to prevent Proguard from obfuscating any classes from the package `com.foo.*`.

I have tried:

```
-keep com.foo.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
    <constructors>;
}
```

But proguard says :

> Error: Unexpected keyword 'com.sun.foo.**' in line 32 of file
>   'obfuscationConfig.pro',   included from argument number 1

I get a similar error if I try `keep name com.foo**` or `keep * com.foo.**`.

Comment: Did you ever find out why this was giving you "Unexpected keyword"? I was using something similar and it used to work but I've been getting the same error recently.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try to use the following:

```
-keep class com.foo.** {
  public protected private *;
}
```

Comment: Won't this just keep everything?

Comment: @tomwhipple it will keep everything in `com.foo` package (and subpackages)

Comment: ... the answer is "Yes", to prevent package-private member obfuscation you must add a new line in the block, `*;` What a user-hateful abomination.

Comment: @tomwhipple Inner classes will still be obfuscated within com.foo and its subpackages.

Comment: Hi, How to keep just one class file this way?

Comment: @Nux you just need to write the full class name instead of a pattern. So line 1 should look like: `-keep class com.foo.FooClass {`