# What happened to DroidText?

Tags: android, pdf, itext, android-droidtext

So I've been playing around with DroidText for a while and want to eventually release an app that uses it. The problem is, their code.google site is down! I don't know what to do, or if I can still use this code. Does anyone know why the site is down? I know the project was originally under the LGPL license, and would like to know if I can release an app assuming I comply with the license, or if (since the project has been shut down) I need to do anything at all.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You can still get the source code here https://github.com/bullda/DroidText

Comment: When I look to source code, it seems to use LGPL version: https://github.com/bullda/DroidText/blob/master/src/core/com/lowagie/text/Document.java

Comment: @LeosLiterak DroidText has always been LGPL: https://web.archive.org/web/20130729165625/http://code.google.com/p/droidtext/

Answer (score 4):

It was based on iText 2.1.7 and it was probably removed for reasons explained on this page: https://itextpdf.com/salesfaq

[iTextG](https://itextpdf.com/product/itextg) is the official iText port for Android.