# Proguard: ignoring package does not prevent warnings

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

Why does having proguard ignore a package not prevent the warnings related to that package?

Background:

I am attempting to apply proguard to a large project.  Predictably, I have lots of warning like this:

```
Warning:net.fortuna.ical4j.model.CalendarFactory: can't find superclass or interface groovy.util.AbstractFactory
Warning:net.fortuna.ical4j.model.CalendarFactory: can't find superclass or interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject
Warning:net.fortuna.ical4j.model.ContentBuilder: can't find superclass or interface groovy.util.FactoryBuilderSupport
Warning:net.fortuna.ical4j.model.ParameterListFactory: can't find superclass or interface groovy.util.AbstractFactory
Warning:net.fortuna.ical4j.model.ParameterListFactory: can't find superclass or interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject
Warning:net.fortuna.ical4j.model.component.AbstractComponentFactory: can't find superclass or interface groovy.util.AbstractFactory
Warning:net.fortuna.ical4j.model.component.AbstractComponentFactory: can't find superclass or interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject
Warning:net.fortuna.ical4j.model.component.XComponentFactory: can't find superclass or interface groovy.util.AbstractFactory
Warning:net.fortuna.ical4j.model.component.XComponentFactory: can't find superclass or interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject
Warning:net.fortuna.ical4j.model.parameter.AbstractParameterFactory: can't find superclass or interface groovy.util.AbstractFactory
Warning:net.fortuna.ical4j.model.parameter.AbstractParameterFactory: can't find superclass or interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject
Warning:net.fortuna.ical4j.model.property.AbstractPropertyFactory: can't find superclass or interface groovy.util.AbstractFactory
```

I thought I could approach this by excluding these packages from proguard until my app runs with proguard enabled. Then, working package-by-package, I could figure out whether I should ignoring the warnings or exclude only the necessary pieces.

I used [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7593502) of how to exclude a package, adding

`-keep class net.fortuna.ical4j.model.** { public protected private *; }`

to my proguard rules file.  However, I get the same warnings as before.  I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14157641/4455466) which suggests using `-keep` in combination with `-dontwarn`, but I don't understand why having proguard ignore the package doesn't prevent the warnings all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping a class will not automatically hide warnings related to this class as they might indicate problems with the configuration or missing inputs.

To hide warnings for a specific package use

```
-dontwarn com.example.**
```

This will only hide *Warnings*, but not *Notes*, which can be hidden like this:

```
-dontnote com.example.**
```

Looking at your specific warning messages, it looks like that you are missing a groovy library that is used and referenced by the ical4j model classes.

Comment: The groovy library is missing because proguard removed it?  I thought it wouldn't remove things that were being directly used/referenced...

Comment: Proguard did not remove this library, the warning is issued when checking the configuration and input before doing any shrinking/obfuscation/optimization.